# Renaming Active Chart

Tags: excel, vba

I have a chart that was created with the following code

```
Sub Macro_1()

  ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(276, xlArea).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("C13:BT22"), PlotBy:=xlColumns
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementLegendRight)

    ActiveChart.Name = "Name_of_this_Chart"

End Sub
```

The issue is that I get an error on this line

```
 ActiveChart.Name = "Name_of_this_Chart"
```

saying "The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type". Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `ChartObject` you need to refer to.

```vb
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count).Name = "Name_of_this_Chart"
```

Comment: Thank you! what does exactly the (1) do on this case?

Comment: It refers to the newly created chart object and should actually be `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count` - I'll update the answer.